# Bokeh Python callback with components

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh

I am not a Web person so forgive-me if this is trivial.
I am trying to create a visualization using bokeh. I am using a custom Jijna template without the default `{{ plot_div|indent(8) }}` as I have my own schema:

```
<!-- *CustomCSS -->
    <style>
    {% include 'plots.css' %}
    </style>

<!-- Bokeh -->
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}

    {{ bokehPlotsScript | safe }}
    {{ bokehSidebarScript |  safe}}

    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <title>Annelida Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">{{sidebar | safe}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">{{bokehPlots | safe}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I add the plots to the template using components:

```
plotScripts, plotsDiv = createBokehPlot(df)
templateElements = dict(bokehPlotsScript=plotScripts, bokehSidebarScript=sidebarScripts, sidebar = sidebarDiv, bokehPlots = plotsDiv)
curdoc().template_variables.update(templateElements
```

where `createBokehPlot` returns a layout with the figure. The sidebar is created in the same manner.

The problem that I have is that by doing this the callbacks from the buttons on the sidebar are not called on the bokeh server side. I think that I have to add my elements to the document with `add_root()` but I am not sure exactly how. Any suggestions?